# Error in subscribeContext

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm currently trying to configure the Fiware Iot Broker with the Configuration Manager (NECongMan) and Fiware Orion as the context producer. I'm having a problem with the NGSI10 subscribeContext operation.

This is the request sent to the IoT Broker:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<subscribeContextRequest>
  <entityIdList>
    <entityId type="Room" isPattern="false">
      <id>Room1</id>
    </entityId>
  </entityIdList>
  <attributeList>
    <attribute>temperature</attribute>
  </attributeList>
  <reference>http://localhost:1028/accumulate</reference>
  <duration>PT1H</duration>
  <notifyConditions>
    <notifyCondition>
      <type>ONCHANGE</type>
      <condValueList>
        <condValue>pressure</condValue>
      </condValueList>
    </notifyCondition>
  </notifyConditions>
  <throttling>PT5S</throttling>
</subscribeContextRequest>
```

The IoTBroker tries to contact Orion issuing a subscribeContextRequest but the duration string is changed:

```
<subscribeContextRequest>
    <entityIdList>
        <entityId
            type="Room"
            isPattern="false">
            <id>
                Room1
                </id>
            </entityId>
        </entityIdList>
    <attributeList>
        <attribute>
            temperature
            </attribute>
        </attributeList>
    <reference>
        http://192.168.16.178:8080/ngsi10/notify
        </reference>
    <duration>
        P0Y0M0DT0H59M58.157S
        </duration>
    <notifyConditions>
        <notifyCondition>
            <type>
                ONCHANGE
                </type>
            <condValueList>
                <condValue>
                    pressure
                    </condValue>
                </condValueList>
            </notifyCondition>
        </notifyConditions>
    <throttling>
        PT5S
        </throttling>
    </subscribeContextRequest>
```

But Orion gives an error (invalid payload: syntax error in duration string). Do you have any idea how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

For one hour, Duration parameter may be P1H instead of PT1H, according to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format, it seems like **PT is used only to avoid ambiguity between P1M for one month and PT1M for one minute**.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Orion 0.26.1 (the last version in the moment of writing this) doesn't support decimal values (as 58.157) for seconds in duration strings. We have created [an issue about that](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1617) and our plan is to have it solved by next release (0.27.0).

Not sure if modifying the way IoTBroker behaves (in order to round up/down the secons to an integer in the request it sends to Orion) would be a valid workaround... I don't know the details about IoTBroker.

**EDIT:** the fix to support decimal fractions in the seconds field has been just implemented in Orion in develop branch, so it will be available in the next Orion version (0.27.0). Alternatively, you could download source code and build the code to get the fix right now.